# Using SQL to print top 5 team_leaders with orders

Tags: mysql, sql

Really sorry for the ambiguous title. I didn't know how to put it into words. So here description,
I have a table with column names :

```
order_id (bigint), 
user_id(bigint) , 
team_leader (text), 
processing_at (date).
```

I am taking the top 5 leaders according to the most number of orders in an entire year. So according to that `top 5 leaders`, I want to find the number of customers who ordered in the month of July. And respective team_leader(top 5 leader) beside it. For example, the output should be like this :

```
---------------------------------
total order  |  team_leader
---------------------------------
(some number    1st leader
of the order of 1st 
leader)

So on to second and 5th
```

I have used query like this. But this throws error:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS TotalNumberOfOrder, team_leader AS Community_leader
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Task 
WHERE processing_at >= '20200701'
AND processing_at <= '20200731') AS T
WHERE T.team_leader = (SELECT team_leader AS Community_leader   
FROM Task Group BY team_leader ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) DESC LIMIT 5) ;
```

Error i am getting is:  In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'T.team_leader'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I am learning `MySQL`. Can anyone help me with this question? I hope I explained the best I could.

Comment: Please add an example of your data and show us the error you are getting.

Comment: Updated now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here, hope this helps:

1. You cannot use "WHERE T.team_leader = (SELECT team_leader AS Community_leader ...)" since the subquery can return more than 1 row, this will fail. You should replace = with IN. But IN is not an optimized way of performing this.
2. Having the LIMIT in the subquery will probably cause you some issues as it might not be supported.

A better approach is the usage of JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.order_id) AS TotalNumberOfOrder, T.team_leader AS Community_leader
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Task 
WHERE processing_at >= '20200701'
AND processing_at <= '20200731') AS T
JOIN 
(SELECT team_leader AS Community_leader   
FROM Task Group BY team_leader ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) DESC LIMIT 5) AS T2 
ON T.team_leader  = T2.Community_leader
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be solved with a correlated query (google it, I wasn't aware they existed when I was learning SQL), I'll just give you the general structure and then you can fill it in/adjust it where necessary.

```
SELECT team_leader, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS TotalNumberOfOrder
FROM Task r
Group by Team_leader
Having 5 > (select count(*) from Task s
             group by Team_leader
             having r.count(order_id) < s.count(order_id))
```

it basically does the following: it iterates through each team_leader and checks how many other team leaders score higher than them. So the first has 0, the second has 1 up till the 5th which has 4 that score higher than them.

I didn't include the WHERE clauses but you can easily add them to the exisiting code.

Comment: Note that you don't need a data set in order to check for syntax errors

Comment: I think you missed a comma after team_leader in the select clause.

Comment: Point missed then :-(